# spring boot xa transaction datasource and jms

Tags: java, spring-boot, jms, activemq-classic, spring-data-jpa

I make a POC with spring-boot-starter-data-jpa and spring-boot-starter-activemq. I would like to push the jms message on the broker (activeMQ) when the jpa transaction was commited.

My code :
UtilsateurService with have the "main" transaction:

```
@Service
public class UtilisateurService {

    @Autowired
    private UtilisateurRepository utilisateurRepository;

    @Autowired
    private SendMessage sendMessage;

    @Transactional(rollbackOn = java.lang.Exception.class)
    public Utilisateur create(Utilisateur utilisateur) throws Exception {
        final Utilisateur result = utilisateurRepository.save(utilisateur);
        sendMessage.send("creation utilisateur : " + result.getId());
        throw new Exception("rollback");
        //return result;
    }
}
```

The SendMessage class witch "manage" Jms message:

```
@Component
public class SendMessage {

    @Autowired
    private JmsMessagingTemplate jmsMessagingTemplate;

    @Value("${jms.queue.destination}")
    private String destinationQueue;

    public void send(String msg) {
        this.jmsMessagingTemplate.convertAndSend(destinationQueue, msg);
    }

}
```

My main class :

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJms
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

The JMS message was push on the activeMq broker before exception was throw. So I don't have "rollback" on the broker.

How can I configure to have xa transaction running?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

is your jmsTemplate Transacted ?

```
jmsTemplate.setSessionTransacted(true);
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/support/JmsAccessor.html#setSessionTransacted-boolean-

> **public void setSessionTransacted(boolean sessionTransacted)**
>
> Set the transaction mode that is used when creating a JMS Session.
>   Default is "false". Note that within a JTA transaction, the parameters
>   passed to create(Queue/Topic)Session(boolean transacted, int
>   acknowledgeMode) method are not taken into account. Depending on the
>   Java EE transaction context, the container makes its own decisions on
>   these values. Analogously, these parameters are not taken into account
>   within a locally managed transaction either, since the accessor
>   operates on an existing JMS Session in this case.
>
> Setting this flag to "true" will use a short local JMS transaction
>   when running outside of a managed transaction, and a synchronized
>   local JMS transaction in case of a managed transaction (other than an
>   XA transaction) being present. This has the effect of a local JMS
>   transaction being managed alongside the main transaction (which might
>   be a native JDBC transaction), with the JMS transaction committing
>   right after the main transaction.

http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077963/open-source-tools/distributed-transactions-in-spring--with-and-without-xa.html

> **30.2.5 Transaction management**
>
> Spring provides a JmsTransactionManager that manages transactions for
>   a single JMS ConnectionFactory. This allows JMS applications to
>   leverage the managed transaction features of Spring as described in
>   Chapter 17, Transaction Management. The JmsTransactionManager performs
>   local resource transactions, binding a JMS Connection/Session pair
>   from the specified ConnectionFactory to the thread. JmsTemplate
>   automatically detects such transactional resources and operates on
>   them accordingly.
>
> In a Java EE environment, the ConnectionFactory will pool Connections
>   and Sessions, so those resources are efficiently reused across
>   transactions. In a standalone environment, using Spring’s
>   SingleConnectionFactory will result in a shared JMS Connection, with
>   each transaction having its own independent Session. Alternatively,
>   consider the use of a provider-specific pooling adapter such as
>   ActiveMQ’s PooledConnectionFactory class.
>
> JmsTemplate can also be used with the JtaTransactionManager and an
>   XA-capable JMS ConnectionFactory for performing distributed
>   transactions. Note that this requires the use of a JTA transaction
>   manager as well as a properly XA-configured ConnectionFactory! (Check
>   your Java EE server’s / JMS provider’s documentation.)
>
> Reusing code across a managed and unmanaged transactional environment
>   can be confusing when using the JMS API to create a Session from a
>   Connection. This is because the JMS API has only one factory method to
>   create a Session and it requires values for the transaction and
>   acknowledgment modes. In a managed environment, setting these values
>   is the responsibility of the environment’s transactional
>   infrastructure, so these values are ignored by the vendor’s wrapper to
>   the JMS Connection. When using the JmsTemplate in an unmanaged
>   environment you can specify these values through the use of the
>   properties sessionTransacted and sessionAcknowledgeMode. When using a
>   PlatformTransactionManager with JmsTemplate, the template will always
>   be given a transactional JMS Session.

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jms.html#jms-tx

Answer (score 1):

Hassen give the solution. So I change the SendMessage class to :

```
@Component
public class SendMessage {

    private final JmsMessagingTemplate jmsMessagingTemplate;

    @Value("${jms.queue.destination}")
    private String destinationQueue;

    @Autowired
    public SendMessage(JmsMessagingTemplate jmsMessagingTemplate) {
        this.jmsMessagingTemplate = jmsMessagingTemplate;
        this.jmsMessagingTemplate.getJmsTemplate().setSessionTransacted(true);
    }

    public void send(String msg) {
        this.jmsMessagingTemplate.convertAndSend(destinationQueue, msg);
    }

}
```